# Return first N key:value pairs from dict

Tags: python, dictionary

Consider the following dictionary, d:

```
d = {'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}
```

I want to return the first N key:value pairs from d (N <= 4 in this case). What is the most efficient method of doing this?

Comment: Caution. Seems to be a lot of misinformation in answers. My tests show not a single solution is faster than `list(d.items())[:4]`. list() is the underlying implementation for many of the answers.

Comment: to those who are wondering, the list() actually converts the given dictionary into a list as such: new_list = [('a', 3), ('b', 2),('c', 3)......]

Comment: be careful with `list(d.items())[:4]` solution because it could change the key orders, for example if you have negative number as key

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Prior to Python 3.6 there is no such thing a the "first n" keys because a `dict` doesn't remember which keys were inserted first.

You can get first `n` iteration sorted key-value pairs though:

```py
n_items = take(n, d.items())
```

This uses the implementation of `take` from the [`itertools` recipes](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```py
from itertools import islice

def take(n, iterable):
    """Return the first n items of the iterable as a list."""
    return list(islice(iterable, n))
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/LLgFX)

**For Python < 3.6**

```py
n_items = take(n, d.iteritems())
```

Comment: I believe `iteritems` should be replaced with `items` for folks on Python 3

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck, brilliant, thank you for adding this comment.

Comment: Beginner here - is `take()` a part of the python code base anywhere? Or, is it purely the function you defined in your answer here? Asking as if it's a part of the code base, I'm not able to find/import it. :)

Comment: I only see `takewhile` in python 3.8 https://devdocs.io/python~3.8/library/itertools#itertools.takewhile

Comment: **This answer is no longer correct**. Python dicts now preserve insertion order, and this is explicitly documented.

Comment: @ScottBorden `take()` now belongs to `more-itertools` package - https://stackoverflow.com/a/64009729/1396334

Comment: **This answer doesn't work longer in python 3.7+** see my answer for the update https://stackoverflow.com/a/64516802/7339624

Comment: @Peyman Your statement is wrong. This answer works perfectly for 3.7 and higher.

Comment: @normanius I use 3.9 and the take implementation with `list(islice(iterable, n))` only returns me the keys without the values

Comment: It is worth noting one should use `dict(take(...))` to get expected results.

Answer (score 145):

A very efficient way to retrieve anything is to combine list or dictionary comprehensions with slicing. If you don't need to order the items (you just want n random pairs), you can use a dictionary comprehension like this:

```
# Python 2
first2pairs = {k: mydict[k] for k in mydict.keys()[:2]}
# Python 3
first2pairs = {k: mydict[k] for k in list(mydict)[:2]}
```

Generally a comprehension like this is always faster to run than the equivalent "for x in y" loop. Also, by using .keys() to make a list of the dictionary keys and slicing that list you avoid 'touching' any unnecessary keys when you build the new dictionary.

If you don't need the keys (only the values) you can use a list comprehension:

```
first2vals = [v for v in mydict.values()[:2]]
```

If you need the values sorted based on their keys, it's not much more trouble:

```
first2vals = [mydict[k] for k in sorted(mydict.keys())[:2]]
```

or if you need the keys as well:

```
first2pairs = {k: mydict[k] for k in sorted(mydict.keys())[:2]}
```

Comment: This one is a better solution if you want to select N many key:value pairs as a dictionary, not as a list

Comment: @fermat4214 Is it an issue, if my entire dictionary prints out when I run any of these commands?

Comment: list(mydict)[:2] is wasteful if you don't need to sort the dictionary and only need the first 2 elements. What if the dictionary has 1 mil k-v pairs? Converting the whole thing to a list is expensive. Mark Byers's solution is much better.

Comment: This should be the solution !

Answer (score 54):

To get the top N elements from your python dictionary one can use the following line of code:

```py
list(dictionaryName.items())[:N]
```

In your case you can change it to:

```py
list(d.items())[:4]
```

Comment: This can be slow if your dictionary is a large one. Look at my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64516802/7339624

Answer (score 19):

Python's `dict`s are not guaranteed to be ordered in Python <= 3.6, so it's meaningless to ask for the "first N" keys in older Python versions.

The [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) class is available if that's what you need. You could efficiently get its first four elements as

```
import itertools
import collections

d = collections.OrderedDict((('foo', 'bar'), (1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd')))
x = itertools.islice(d.items(), 0, 4)

for key, value in x:
    print key, value
```

[`itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) allows you to lazily take a slice of elements from any iterator. If you want the result to be reusable you'd need to convert it to a list or something, like so:

```
x = list(itertools.islice(d.items(), 0, 4))
```

Comment: Not looking lazy. Takes 2x longer than `list(d.items())[:4]

Answer (score 15):

```
foo = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4, 'e':5, 'f':6}
iterator = iter(foo.items())
for i in range(3):
    print(next(iterator))
```

Basically, turn the view (dict_items) into an iterator, and then iterate it with next().

Comment: Fantastic answer, this is the only answer on this page that worked for me and is also readable.  Also, I can verify this works with Python 3, which some of the older answers don't seem to.

Answer (score 15):

You can get dictionary items by calling `.items()` on the dictionary. then convert that to a `list` and from there get first N items as you would on any list.

below code prints first 3 items of the dictionary object

e.g.

```
d = {'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}

first_three_items = list(d.items())[:3]

print(first_three_items)
```

Outputs:

```
[('a', 3), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
```

Answer (score 13):

Unfortunately, most of the answers are not efficient. This is the most efficient way that I know of. Were `d` is your dictionary and `n` is the printing number:

```
for idx, k in enumerate(d):
  if idx == n: break
  print((k, d[k]))
```

Here `idx` means index and `k` means key. Consequently `d[k]` will be the value.

### Casting your dictionary to a list can be slow:

Your dictionary may be too large and you don't need to cast all of it just for printing a few of the first. Both `list(d.items())` and `list(d.keys())` are slow.

### Time Performance Comparison:

Here is the time comparison of the three methods. Random dictionaries were generated from lengths 10 to 1000, and their 5 first elements were printed. As you can see the performance of `enumerate(d)` is O(1) and won't be changed by the length of the dictionary. This is not true for `list(d.items())` and `list(d.keys())` which are O(n).
[image]

Comment: The for loop `for idx, (k, v) in enumerate(d):` should probably be `for idx, (k, v) in enumerate(d.items()):` so that (k,v) tuple is returned?

Comment: I get an error:  TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.int64 object

Comment: @AshokKHarnal It is fixed.

Answer (score 11):

in py3, this will do the trick

```
{A:N for (A,N) in [x for x in d.items()][:4]}
```

{'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}

Answer (score 9):

For **Python 3.8** the correct answer should be:

```
import more_itertools

d = {'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}

first_n = more_itertools.take(3, d.items())
print(len(first_n))
print(first_n)
```

Whose output is:

```
3
[('a', 3), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
```

After `pip install more-itertools` of course.

Comment: first_n = dict(more_itertools.take(3, d.items()))

Answer (score 7):

Did not see it on here. Will not be ordered but the simplest syntactically if you need to just take some elements from a dictionary.

```
n = 2
{key:value for key,value in list(d.items())[0:n]}
```

Comment: I tried you code but I get this error:
`TypeError: 'dict_items' object is not subscriptable`

`{key:value for key,value in stocks.items()[0:n]}`     (stocks is the name of my dictionary)

Comment: @Moondra - Have to convert into the list before running through dictionary items. Above code, line works if {key:value for key,value in list(d.items())[0:n]}

Comment: {A:N for (A,N) in [x for x in d.items()][:4]}

Answer (score 4):

This will work for python 3.8+:

```
d_new = {k:v for i, (k, v) in enumerate(d.items()) if i < n}
```

Answer (score 3):

See [PEP 0265](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0265/) on sorting dictionaries.  Then use the aforementioned iterable code.

If you need more efficiency in the sorted key-value pairs.  Use a different data structure.  That is, one that maintains sorted order and the key-value associations.

E.g.

```py
import bisect

kvlist = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('e', 5)]
bisect.insort_left(kvlist, ('d', 4))

print kvlist # [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4), ('e', 5)]
```

Answer (score 2):

just add an answer using zip,

```
{k: d[k] for k, _ in zip(d, range(n))}
```

Comment: Another `zip` variant: `{key:val for (key, val), _ in zip(d.items(), range(n))}`

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what is 'most efficient' in your case.

If you just want a semi-random sample of a huge dictionary `foo`, use `foo.iteritems()` and take as many values from it as you need, it's a lazy operation that avoids creation of an explicit list of keys or items.

If you need to sort keys first, there's no way around using something like `keys = foo.keys(); keys.sort()` or `sorted(foo.iterkeys())`, you'll have to build an explicit list of keys. Then slice or iterate through first N `keys`.

BTW why do you care about the 'efficient' way? Did you profile your program? If you did not, use the *obvious* and *easy to understand* way first. Chances are it will do pretty well without becoming a bottleneck.

Comment: This was an application to a financial program and I attempt to build every line of code as efficiently as possible. I did not profile the program and agree this will probably not be a bottle neck but I like to ask for efficient solutions by default. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

For Python 3 and above,To select first n Pairs

```
n=4
firstNpairs = {k: Diction[k] for k in list(Diction.keys())[:n]}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might not be very elegant, but works for me:

```
d = {'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}

x= 0
for key, val in d.items():
    if x == 2:
        break
    else:
        x += 1
        # Do something with the first two key-value pairs
```

Answer (score 1):

I like this one because no new list needs to be created, its a one liner which does exactly what you want and it works with python >= 3.8 (where dictionaries are indeed ordered, I think from python 3.6 on?):

```
new_d = {kv[0]:kv[1] for i, kv in enumerate(d.items()) if i <= 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this a number of ways.  If order is important you can do this:

```
for key in sorted(d.keys()):
  item = d.pop(key)
```

If order isn't a concern you can do this:

```
for i in range(4):
  item = d.popitem()
```

Comment: In the first snippet you should probably call it `value` rather than `item` for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary maintains no order , so before picking top N key value pairs lets make it sorted.

```
import operator
d = {'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
d=dict(sorted(d.items(),key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True))
#itemgetter(0)=sort by keys, itemgetter(1)=sort by values
```

Now we can do the retrieval of top 'N' elements:, using the method structure like this:

```
def return_top(elements,dictionary_element):
    '''Takes the dictionary and the 'N' elements needed in return
    '''
    topers={}
    for h,i in enumerate(dictionary_element):
        if h<elements:
            topers.update({i:dictionary_element[i]})
    return topers
```

to get the top 2 elements then simply use this structure:

```
d = {'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
d=dict(sorted(d.items(),key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True))
d=return_top(2,d)
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

consider a dict

```
d = {'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}

from itertools import islice
n = 3
list(islice(d.items(),n))
```

islice will do the trick :) 
hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a few of the answers above and note that some of them are version dependent and do not work in version 3.7.

I also note that since 3.6 all dictionaries are ordered by the sequence in which items are inserted.

Despite dictionaries being ordered since 3.6 some of the statements you expect to work with ordered structures don't seem to work.

The answer to the OP question that worked best for me.

```
itr = iter(dic.items())
lst = [next(itr) for i in range(3)]
```

Comment: FYI, 5x slower than `lst = list(d.items())[:N]`

Comment: @BSalita While that’s true for tiny dictionaries, the performance becomes more interesting for huge dictionaries, since the solution posted here is (in principle) asymptotically faster. In practice, it’s more or less on par even for huge dictionaries (10M elements).

Answer (score 0):

```
def GetNFirstItems(self):
    self.dict = {f'Item{i + 1}': round(uniform(20.40, 50.50), 2) for i in range(10)}#Example Dict
    self.get_items = int(input())
    for self.index,self.item in zip(range(len(self.dict)),self.dict.items()):
        if self.index==self.get_items:
          break
        else:
            print(self.item,",",end="")
```

Unusual approach, as it gives out intense O(N) time complexity.