# How to iterate over the first n elements of a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, slice

Simple question here:

If I try to slice my dictionary (parsed from an xml file)  in python, I will get a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'`

```
for section in my_dict[:3] ['CATEGORY']['SUBCATEGORY']:
```

it looks like it doesn't work for dictionaries, do they have a specific method? Or is it because of the 2 other arguments coming right after that are misinterpreted?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42885488/python-typeerror-unhashable-type-slice)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [take the first x elements of a dictionary on python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976096/take-the-first-x-elements-of-a-dictionary-on-python)

Comment: In your link, the best answer uses slice that doesn't work with dictionaries. If you use slice `[:n]` you will get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```py
from itertools import islice

d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
for item in islice(d, 3):  # use islice(d.items(), 3) to iterate over key/value pairs
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
```

Comment: `for item in islice(my_dict.['CATEGORY']['SUBCATEGORY']), 3):`
gives me a synthax error

Comment: `my_dict.['CATEGORY']['SUBCATEGORY']` is not valid syntax, you cannot put `.` before `[...]`. If you want to go through elements in a sub-dictionary in `my_dict['CATEGORY']['SUBCATEGORY']`, then do `islice(my_dict['CATEGORY']['SUBCATEGORY'], 3)` (without the `.`), if you want to access the value at `['CATEGORY']['SUBCATEGORY']` for each of the first three items use `for key, value in islice(my_dict.items()), 3): print(value['CATEGORY']['SUBCATEGORY'])`