# Python Print The First Five elements of a dictionary

Tags: python, printing, ordereddictionary

I have a dictionary which the key are strings and the values are integers. im using a loop to print the an ordered vision of said dictionary. My code looks like this:

```
for k,v in sorted(my_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)):
    print (k,v)
```

Which gives me an output like this:

```
Key Value
```

How can i print only the first five entries of this dictionary?

Also, is it possible to separate the ouput to "A: 5" instead of "A 5"?

Thanks!

Comment: `sorted(my_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[:5]`

Comment: `print("{}: {}".format(k,v))`

Comment: something similar has already been posted here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971618/python-return-first-n-keyvalue-pairs-from-dict

Answer (score 2):

You can access up to a certain point on your

`sorted(my_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))`

dictionary using [:n], where n is the number of elements you want to access.

```
 for k,v in sorted(my_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[:5]:
    print (k,v)
```