# Get the top N values from each row of a Pandas dataframe with their respective Column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, series

```
Index          Class 1               Class 2         Class 3         Class 4          Class 5  
0              0.95693475            0.252198994      0.0            0.335894585      0.611441553
1              0.473615974           0.0              0.510585248    0.5007305        0.975620011
2              0.224682823           0.122315248      0.6407305        0.0            0.872211390
```

This is a sample of the dataframe I am working on. I have around `200 Class's` in my original dataframe and around 85000 rows and for each row of my dataframe I want to find out the top 3 Categories with their values sorted in descending order:

```
    Expected output:
    Row 0: [{Class 1 : 95693475}, {Class 5: 0.611441553}, {Class 4: 0.335894585}]
    Row 1: [{Class 5 : 0.975620011}, {Class 3: 0.510585248}, {Class 4: 0.5007305}]
etc etc...
```

Note: List and dict in the expected output are just added for reference, just need to output the top 3 scores with their category names for each row in the dataframe. Can anyone help me with this

Comment: What have you tried so far @Erich ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**References :**

[Apply funtion to row in pandas - Example 3](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/apply-function-to-every-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe/)

[Return first n keyvalue pairs from dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971618/python-return-first-n-keyvalue-pairs-from-dict)

To return the first n keyvalue pairs from dict

```py
from itertools import islice
def take(n, iterable):
    return list(islice(iterable, n))
```

drop the Index Column

```py
df.drop('Index', axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Function that can be applied to all rows to find the topmost 3 categories

The `topN` function takes as input parameter `row` : which would be a row of the dataframe and `n` : denoting how many topmost elements you want to extract.

```py
def topN(row, n):
    x = row.to_dict() # convert the input row to a dictionary 
    x = {k: v for k, v in sorted(x.items(), key=lambda item: -item[1])} # sort the dictionary based on their values 
    n_items = take(n, x.items()) # extract the first n values from the dictionary 
    return n_items
n = 3 #number of elements needed
df['X'] = df.apply(lambda row : topN(row,n), axis = 1)
```

**Output :**

A new column `X` with the required result as dictionaries is stored. You can convert the column into an array too.

```
Class 1 Class 2 Class 3 Class 4 Class 5 X
0   0.956935    0.252199    0.000000    0.335895    0.611442    [(Class 1, 0.95693475), (Class 5 , 0.61144155...
1   0.473616    0.000000    0.510585    0.500731    0.975620    [(Class 5 , 0.975620011), (Class 3, 0.5105852...
2   0.224683    0.122315    0.640730    0.000000    0.872211    [(Class 5 , 0.87221139), (Class 3, 0.6407305)...
```

Example to remove all values with `0.0` :

```
d = {1:0.0, 2:0.0, 3:1.0}
x={k:v for k,v in d.items() if v}
x # prints {3: 1.0}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain your topN function. Also in a row, if there are all 0.0 values except a value of 1.0, how to only get 1 input i.e 1.0 for the scenario and not 3 outputs

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I would like to understand why you are doing x.items in the line where you are assigning x to the sorted dictionary. Also while trying to filter out the keys with 0.0, I tried this code `x = {k: v for k, v in sorted(x.items() if v != '0.0', key=lambda item: -item[1])}` but it's giving me a syntax error

Comment: Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: A dictionary is not iterable usually, we can use the `.items()` to iterate through it. And make your code simpler, remove the `0.0` before you the sorting line.

Comment: You mean I should keep it like `x = {k: v for k, v in sorted(x.items() if v, key=lambda item: -item[1])}` to filter out the keys with 0.0 values? This is also giving a syntax error

Comment: Don't change the line where the dictionary is sorted. Before that include another line : `x={k:v for k,v in x.items() if v}` where you can include only those keys from the dictionary that have non-zero values. Refer the example at the bottom of my answer.