# Return the next N items from a Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, chunks

This is a common pattern, we want to return enough of some iterable to satisfy a consumer, for example a batch process or a page display.  In this case we want it in ascending key order, and as a bonus the dictionary was also created in ascending key order, though there may be gaps. The keys are positive integers.

E.G.

```
{1: "Genesis", 2: "Exodus", 4: "Leviticus", ... , 557: "Revelation"}
```

There is an existing question which covers getting the first N items at [Return first N key:value pairs from dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971618/return-first-n-keyvalue-pairs-from-dict) . One of the interesting points in the comments is that, since Python 3.6, dictionaries iterate in insertion order.

Questions:

1. If dictionary entries are updated is this iteration order preserved?
2. Given the key of the last entry of the previous page, is there an elegant Pythonic way  to get the next N entries in key order? (Failing that is there an inelegant way?)

--edit--

Clarification:
If we know, for example, that "Matthew"  has an id of 100, we should be able to call:

```
answer = foo(100, 4)
```

and get answer:

```
{100: "Matthew", 102: "Mark", 103: "Luke", 107: "John}
```

When we get the next 4 entries, however, we only know that the first one will be the smallest key greater than 107, could be 108, could be 500.

Since the dictionary is potentially huge it's not elegant to copy all the keys, or iterate through the entire collection.  (In my use case it's probably cheap, but I'd *prefer* a solution that's smarter.)

Comment: `dict(islice(dropwhile(lambda x: x[0] < 100, d.items()), 4))`. Imports: [`dropwhile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile), [`islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice).

Answer (score 1):

1. The order is based on the keys - not the values. Therefore, if a value is updated the order (key) will be preserved
2. You could get the dictionary's keys as a list. Find the index of the key you're interested in then get values based on the next N keys in that list